# scrollable curved wheel View

Tags: java, android, animation, user-interface, gestures

is it possible to get or create a wheel of selectable options, which scrolls in an imaginary circle rather than straight down (vertically)?

### Straight Link But Want Curved

e.g. like the control **[here](http://android-devblog.blogspot.com/2010/05/wheel-ui-contol.html)**, but with the wheels curved?

Comment: With difficulty... If you're after a 3D effect I would look into opengl-es implementation

Comment: @Jack i found a way to turn the straight wheel - I - into a curved one - ) - by overriding OnDraw and rotating elements, but the result suffers from performance issues / is a bit laggy - is there any way to accelerate the drawing given im not using any opengl?

Comment: are you currently drawing every frame? if needs be you could set it so that it only draws when an input event is registered

Comment: wheelview with circlulation or straight vertically?? what abt view icant exaplain proper;;;;;;;;;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that what you want is a carousel? http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/androcarousel.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it, if you read the blog you've linked to it will give you some clues on how to do it. Or you can check out [this project on googlecode](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/) where they already have it implemented.

Comment: sorry, i dont mean curved into the screen, but curved horizontally to the right side, like part of the letter O ?

Comment: I don't think the widget is actually curved. It looks that way because of the shading but if you look closely you can see the widget is straight.

Comment: my main aim is to make it curved though, like so )